# How to create a ZIP file that prints a message upon extraction?

Tags: zip

Recently, I have encountered a zip file (containing a single file) that printed a custom message to standard out when I ran

```bsh
unzip archive.zip
```

without further arguments.

I was not aware that this is possible. I did read up about file comments in the ZIP specification, but they seem to behave differently on the CLI.

When I used `zip -c` and entered a custom message, I could see that my custom message somehow gets compressed into the archive, but it won't print automatically when unzipping the file again.

Using `unzip -l` lets me view my message—but that is not how the original file `archive.zip` behaved. `unzip -l archive.zip` first prints the custom message, and then lists the archive contents. In opposite to my experiments with file comments, the comment is not printed in the list.

Therefore my question: **how can I create a ZIP file that prints a custom message upon extraction?** (And also, what is this feature called, if not file comments?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `--archive-comment`. Quote from manpage:

```
       -z
       --archive-comment
              Prompt  for a multi-line comment for the entire zip archive.  The comment is ended by a line containing just a period, or an end of file condition (^D on Unix, ^Z on MSDOS, OS/2, and
              VMS).  The comment can be taken from a file:

                     zip -z foo < foowhat
```

`zip --archive-comment -c -r test test` prompts user to enter a special comment for the entire archive.

During extraction (Message is Hello):

```
unzip ../test.zip
Archive:  ../test.zip
Hello.
   creating: test/
 extracting: test/test.txt
```